# What is the best implementation of the Facebook like-button you've seen?

Tags: facebook

I'm looking into implementing the Facebook like-button on my site. Therefore i'm looking for some good examples of the use of the like-button.

I'm looking at the placement of the like-button and the use of the Open Graph meta-properties.

Please explain why you like a particular implementation

Comment: I've made this community wiki since it is a poll.

Comment: I think this question is incorrectly framed. I'd suggest that it would be a more useful question to ask which *factors* are important in implementing links to social networking sites in general. As stated it is highly subjective.

Answer (score 2):

[AddThis](http://addthis.com/) allows sharing to multiple different social sites, including Facebook.

Comment: It's not an implementation of the facebook like button though, is it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Host the button on your own server that Facebook can't track all your visitors.

The placement really depends on what type of site (blog, etc.) you want to use it on. So I think you should provide more information (maybe a link, if it is possible).

My favorite placement is on the left or right side of the browser window on which the buttons scrolls with you're scrolling. So the button get more attention than a static place. Maybe you can hide it with some arrow which - on click - displays it.

Answer (score 0):

[ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) allows sharing to multiple different social sites, including Facebook.